# concrete5 no name no description no styling of theme

Tags: themes, concrete5

I have installed my theme in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\c5\surreymarketingpr_gmk\packages\dotawesome_warm\themes\dotawesome
its working fine on localhost but not on live site. Also its an older version of concrete5 because this theme is not compatible with the latest versions of concrete5.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't really giving enough information here. Not working is not very helpful.  What do your error logs contain?  What's the website URL?

There are several things that can impact uploading to an online host, such as PHP version, MySQL version, .htaccess settings, file permissions, etc.

Another very possible problem is that you didn't have this in your **my.ini** under XAMPP when you installed concret5:

```
lower_case_table_names=1
```

If you'd like help with this you can contact me jasteele12 at [concrete5.org](http://www.concrete5.org/r/-/13433)